# Recommendation for multi-platform, portable, learning mode Git GUI?

Tags: git, msysgit, portable-applications

Any recommendations for a good Git GUI. Should ideally have the following characteristics:

1. Not be very limiting i.e. can support relatively complex functions e.g. rebase, no-ff
2. Shows Git commands being executed in a "learning mode", especially for commands with lots of options
3. Preferably portable (does not require windows installation OR even if only windows, works like a portable application)
4. Preferably multi-platform (so there is no learning curve between my linux machine and windows laptop.

Answer (score 4):

[Git extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) supports almost all operations (for example, it supports interactive rebase). It also shows command line used for the launched operation.

**Update:**
  This is incorrect: *Unfortunately it is Windows-only*. It may work on linux: **Git Extensions runs on multiple platforms using Mono.**

Comment: Where does it show the command line used for the launched operation - the documentation and screenshots don't show it.

Comment: Also, the downloads page actually shows a zip file download labelled Windows and Linux, though all the files are windows specific. If it shows the command line and has a linux version, this would indeed be a very useful tool.

Comment: @rraheja You may see command line in video tutorial mentioned on the project page:  [1 Clone - Git Extensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlZXSkJGKF8) (1 minute after start of the video)

Comment: @rraheja It seems, that it may work on linux: **Git Extensions runs on multiple platforms using Mono** I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't for Windows or Linux, but [Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) for Mac is extremely good. It does rebase, push, merges, checkouts, branching, remote branches, stashing, and more.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). Being a pure Java application portability between Linux and Windows is no issue. The only requirements are a JRE and a Git installation.

It supports virtually all important Git commands, the only important feature missing IMO is  interactive rebasing. Normal rebasing and merging is supported, though.

I think SmartGit fulfills all your requirements except (2.) as it doesn't show any Git commands executed at all.